# KineticJS and shapes inside area

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am looking for the fastest way to find all shapes inside an area. 
Please try this example in Chrome or FireFox: http://jsfiddle.net/markusleth/FBjKY/

I know how to iterate and compare coordinates, but I am worried about performance. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
var x1, x2, y1, y2;
var shapes = stage.get("Rect");
shapes.each(function (shape) {
   // calculate if shape is inside x1, x2, y1, y2
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, KineticJS has a few intersection functions:

`intersects(point)` [Kinetic.Shape#intersects](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#intersects)

`getAllIntersections(pos)` [Kinetic.Container#getAllIntersections](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#getAllIntersections)

`getIntersection(pos)` [Kinetic.Stage#getIntersection](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#getIntersection)

Although `getAllIntersections` is probably the function you need, it looks like the author of KineticJS strongly recommends to use `getIntersection` **IF** possible over `getAllIntersections`. This is because `getAllIntersections` has poor performance when called multiple times consecutively, which is probably a problem for you.

In my experience, `getIntersection` only retrieves 1 object that intersects the point and it seems to only return the latest object added to the stage, that intersects the point! I'm not sure how you would use this in your situation.

User EliteOctagon wrote his own collision detection function with better success (and better performance!): [HTML5 / kineticJS getIntersection function implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875119/html5-kineticjs-getintersection-function-implementation) This might be your best bet. Good luck!

Oh and another small tip on performance: if you are trying to select shapes rather than just "Rectangles", it would work better if you named **all** selectable shapes the same name, and use the `.get()` function on the name instead of just `.get("Rect")`.

For example:

```
new Kinetic.Rect({
  name: "selectableShape"
});

new Kinetic.Ellipse({
  name: "selectableShape"
});

var selectableShapes = stage.get(".selectableShape");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I came to the same conclusion:  
  
1. The current version of the Kineticjs API will not do it very well, future versions may add better collision detection features  
2. I need to come up with my own “algorithm”  
I decided to calculate the center of the shape and check if it is inside the selection areas. It will do for now:  
  
http://jsfiddle.net/markusleth/FBjKY/

Comment: I wish I knew how to add linebrakes. Double space does not work…