# Drawing a rectangle on mousemove and selecting all shapes within that rectangle on mouseup using kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I have `selectionrectangle` on `mousemove`(working fine). Can anybody suggest me, how to select shapes within that rectangles range on `mouseup` event? My code is like(only main functions):

```
function onMouseDown() {
             if (!isMouseDown) {
                 return
             }
             isMouseDown = true;
             if (selectionrectangle) {
                 selectionrectangle.remove();
             }
             pointerPosition = stage.getPointerPosition();
             x = Math.floor(pointerPosition.x)
             y = Math.floor(pointerPosition.y )
             originX = [];
             originY = [];
             originX.push(x);
             originY.push(y);
             selectionrectangle = new Kinetic.Rect({
                 x: originX[0],
                 y: originY[0],
                 width: 0,
                 height: 0,
                 stroke: 'pink',
                 strokeWidth: 3,
                 name: 'SelectionRectangle'
             });
             refRect = selectionrectangle;
             refRect1 = selectionrectangle;
             selectionrectangle.setListening(true);
             mainLayer.add(selectionrectangle);
         }
         function onMouseMove() {
             if (!isMouseDown) {
                 return;
             };
             isMouseDown = true;
             pointerPosition = stage.getPointerPosition();
             x = Math.floor(pointerPosition.x )
             y = Math.floor(pointerPosition.y)
             refRect.setWidth(x - refRect.getX());
             refRect.setHeight(y - refRect.getY());
             mainLayer.drawScene();
         }
         function onMouseUp() {
             isMouseDown = false;
             stage.add(mainLayer);
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using bounding-boxes is an excellent way to testing for enclosure.**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/f9pe4/

**A bounding box consists of a selection's leftmost, rightmost, top and bottom coordinates.**

The bounding box of your refRect can be put into an object like this:

```
// calculate a bounding box for the refRect

refRect.BoundingBox=refBoundingBox(refRect);

function refBoundingBox(refRect){
    return({
        left:refRect.getX(),
        top:refRect.getY(),
        right:refRect.getX()+refRect.getWidth(),
        bottom:refRect.getY()+refRect.getHeight()
    });
}
```

**Then you can test all your shapes against that bounding box.**

All core Kinetic shapes fall into 4 categories:

- Rectangular: Rect, Image, Text, Sprite,
- Circular: Circle, Wedge,
- Polypoint: Line, Polygon, Blob, Spline
- Undefinable structure: Custom (not examined in this answer)

**Testing Rectangular shapes: Rect, Image, Text, Sprite:**

```
// Test enclosure for rectangular shapes:
// Rect,Image,Text,Sprite

function isRectInBB(refBB,shape){
    var x=shape.getX();
    var y=shape.getY();
    return( 
        x>refBB.left &&
        x+shape.getWidth()<refBB.right &&
        y>refBB.top &&
        y+shape.getHeight()<refBB.bottom
    );
}
```

**Testing Circular shapes: Circle, Wedge:**

```
// Test enclusure for circular shapes:
// Circle,Wedge

function isCircleInBB(refBB,shape){
    var thisX=shape.getX();
    var thisY=shape.getY();
    var thisRadius=shape.getRadius();
    return( 
        thisX-thisRadius>refBB.left &&
        thisX+thisRadius<refBB.right &&
        thisY-thisRadius>refBB.top &&
        thisY+thisRadius<refBB.bottom
    );
}
```

**Testing Polypoint shapes:  Line, Polygon, Blob, Spline:**

```
// Test enclosure for polypoint shapes:
// Line,Polygon,Blob,Spline

function isPolyInBB(refBB,shape){
    var x=shape.getX();
    var y=shape.getY();
    return(
        x+shape.minX>refBB.left &&
        y+shape.minY>refBB.top &&
        x+shape.maxX<refBB.right &&
        y+shape.maxY<refBB.bottom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this old question: [KineticJS and shapes inside area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486155/kineticjs-and-shapes-inside-area/17493499#17493499)

I provide some information and background on how to solve your question, along with the OP has a JSFiddle example that will help get you started.