# How to determine a shape touches another shape or not using kineticjs?

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a number of shapes in my kinetc layer. If I drag and drop a shape somewhere else in the layer, how to determine the dropped shape touches another shape or not?

Comment: KineticJS does not have built-in collision detection. You'll have to do collision testing mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you need to do is create a mathematical representation of the shapes you have. For most simple collision detection, you can use bounding-boxes.

Basically, if you have a circle, you can create a representation of it as being bounded in a box.
Then if you have a square, you can check if the bounding box of the square (which is the square itself) is intersecting with the bounding box of the circle.

I wrote an answer to this a while ago: [HTML5 / kineticJS getIntersection function implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875119/html5-kineticjs-getintersection-function-implementation)

```
 function checkCollide(pointX, pointY, objectx, objecty, objectw, objecth) { // pointX, pointY belong to one rectangle, while the object variables belong to another rectangle
      var oTop = objecty;
      var oLeft = objectx; 
      var oRight = objectx+objectw;
      var oBottom = objecty+objecth; 

      if(pointX > oLeft && pointX < oRight){
           if(pointY > oTop && pointY < oBottom ){
                return 1;
           }
      }
      else
           return 0;
 };
```

used like this:

```
 var children = layer.getChildren();
 for( var i=0; i<children.length; i++){  // for each single shape
     for( var j=0; j<children.length; j++){ //check each other shape
         if(i != j){ //skip if shape is the same
            if(checkCollide(children[i].getX(), children[i].getY(), children[j].getX(), children[j].getY(), children[j].getWidth(), children[j].getHeight()))
                alert('top left corner collided');
         }
     }
 }
```

This works great if the shape you have is a rectangle of some sort, but not that great if you have two circles, as they have a radius. So this suffices for a quick check of collision, next you need another function which will check collisions more precisely.

You can also try using kineticjs with box2d, there are a bunch of tutorials out there on the topic.